# what do block/inline do inside non-flow layouts?

Tags: css

CSS beginner here, so I might be misunderstanding...

From what I understand, an element has

1. an outer display value: block/inline
2. an inner display value: flow, grid, flex (and a few others)

If the parents inner display is "flow", the childrens' outer display determines how they are laid out inside the parent. But what happens if the parent element inner layout is not flow?? What do the children outer values do in that case?? Is there any resource describing in detail how the parent's inner display interacts with the children's outer display in general??

Comment: There are some good starting points to understand how children of flex and grid containers behave: 

(flexbox) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#specifying_what_elements_to_lay_out_as_flexible_boxes 

(grid) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#grid_container

Comment: Basically, the children become either flex items or grid items. You can search for the properties and behaviour of these two types of items.

Comment: Another set of really useful resources: (check the "properties for the children" sections)

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/